# get() returned more than one TenantUser

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

my views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
@csrf_exempt
def transfer_tokens(request, domain):
    """
        transfer tokens
    """
    email = request.data['to_email']
    # user_id = request.data['connected']
    user = request.user
    coins_to_be_transferred = request.data["coins"]
    to_user = User.objects.get(email=email)
    user_id = to_user.id
    to_tuser = TenantUser.global_manager.get(user=user_id)
    tenantuser = TenantUser.global_manager.get(email=user.email)
    if to_user and user.kyc_done and to_user.kyc_done and coins_to_be_transferred >= 0:
        if user.coins >= coins_to_be_transferred:
            PoolHistory._default_manager.create(
                tenant=tenantuser, coins=coins_to_be_transferred, loss=True)
            user.coins = get_coins(tenantuser)
            user.save()
            PoolHistory._default_manager.create(
                tenant=to_tuser, coins=coins_to_be_transferred, profit=True)
            message = "You have received %s tokens from %s" % (coins_to_be_transferred, tenantuser.name)
            notification = Notifications(user=to_user, message=message)
            notification.save()
            return Response({"detail": "Tokens have been transferred successfully.", "coins": user.coins}, status=200)
        else:
            return Response({"detail": "Your account has insufficient tokens to complete the transfer."}, status=400)
    else:
        if not coins_to_be_transferred >= 0:
            return Response({"detail": "Tokens can't be transferred."}, status=400)
        if not to_user.kyc_done:
            return Response({"detail": "User with email isn't verified."}, status=400)
        else:
            return Response({"detail": "email doesn't exist."}, status=400)
```

Comment: Please try to elaborate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `Queryset.get()` behaviour is documented - it's supposed to return one single record, so it will indeed raise if the lookup returns more than one (which is the obvious sensible thing to do - how would the ORM guess which of those records you want ?). IOW, only use `Queryset.get()` for lookups that are garanteed to return __at most__ one single record. Also and FWIW, it will raise a `Model.DoesNotExist` if no matching record is found, so you have to handle this case too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have multiple users having the same email thus you cant use `get()` for that

Workaround :

1. change your model and add `unique=True` for the `email` field. first delete the duplicate emails.

or

1. change this line `to_user = User.objects.get(email=email)` to `to_user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()`